# How to assign values from array to strings java

Tags: java, android

Hello i have an array that is filled with values from database and those values i want to assign them to strings i did this code but its making error:

```
        String[] options = s.split(",");
        String visible = options[0];
        String sms = options[1];
        String contact = options[2];
        String calllogs = options[3];
```

I want the values to separate in array and then by index position to delcare them on each string.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @Pirate First the String visible doesn get only 1 value but gets all values and then at option[1] goes in error making app crash.

Comment: can you add example values in the question? like what are the values in s that you are trying to split.

Comment: Are you sure `s` contains values separated by a comma?

Comment: @Pirate sorry there is no error but all the strings get all the values example sms = 1000 while it should be sms = 0;

Comment: @Pirate no S has no values with coma

Comment: Then why are you splitting by comma?

Comment: if s = "sms=1000" then it can't be split into multiple values.

Comment: @Pirate how can i split them with coma i used that method s.split(" ");

Comment: to split them with comma, string should have comma.

Comment: please add example value in the question then only we can provide some answer to this.

Comment: If each digit of that value is supposed to be a different thing, it can, using `charAt()` in a loop, assigning each to a position of an array, and then each value in the array to a String

Comment: @Pirate the 1000 are values that must be s = 1,0,0,0 and then they are assigned by index position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this Technique.

```
String s = "1000";
  String[] options = new String[s.length()];
  for(int i=0; i< s.length(); i++)
    options[i] = Character.toString(s.charAt(i));
```

But since you are storing chars the array could be declared as char array

Comment: Then can i make `String sms = option[1];` to give specific value to a string?

Comment: Yes, you can assign the values to specific String variables. But you wouldn't need to store it in an array in the first place, you can just use charAt() alone to access the char at the specific index in the String

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value from your string like this.

```
String string = "1000";
char[] options = string.toCharArray();
String visible = options[0];
String sms = options[1];
String contact = options[2];
String calllogs = options[3];
```

or you can directly use charAt() method to get the value at a particular index.

```
String visible = string.charAt(0);
String sms = string.charAt(1);
String contact = string.charAt(2);
String calllogs = string.charAt(3);
```